# Acquiring and Releasing Connections with TcpClient Connection Pool (Reactor Netty)

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have configured TcpClient as described in the examples [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_connection_pool). I am trying to make the following code resilient in situations where the server unexpectedly closes the connection:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = getTcpClient();

public Mono<String> sendMessage(Mono<bytes[]> request) {
    Connection connection = getConnectionFromPool(tcpClient);
    return connection
        .outbound()
        .sendByteArray(request)
        .then()
        .then(connection.inbound().receive().asString().as(Mono::from));
}
```

In such an event, I expect the method "getConnectionFromPool" to be able to retrieve a connection from the pool or open a new one if none are available.

After noticing .connect() eventually defers to ConnectionProvider.acquire(), I tried to use tcpClient.connect(), but it becomes necessary to change the method return type as follows:

```
public Mono<Mono<String>> sendMessage1(Mono<String> request) {
    return this.tcpClient
        .connect()
        .map(connection ->
            connection
                .outbound()
                .sendByteArray(request.map(String::getBytes))
                .then()
                .then(connection.inbound().receive().asString().as(Mono::from))
            );
}
```

Clearly this is undesirable. How do I acquire a Connection instance directly from the pool? Is there a simple Mono operator I am missing, or am I using the TcpClient API incorrectly?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `flatMap` instead of `map`?

```
public Mono<String> sendMessage1(Mono<String> request) {
    return this.tcpClient
            .connect()
            .flatMap(connection ->
                    connection
                            .outbound()
                            .sendByteArray(request.map(String::getBytes))
                            .then()
                            .then(connection.inbound().receive().asString().as(Mono::from))
            );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that solves my issue with the bad return type :) Rookie mistake. I have moved forward with my testing, but I am facing one issue still. Again, my goal is to be able to acquire and reuse Connections from the pool. Currently, with a pool containing 1 Connection, I am unable to use the Connection more than once. Nothing in the wiretap logs indicate the connection is being closed. Am I not releasing the Connection to the pool correctly? Is there a way to release the Connection to the pool _without_ closing the connection? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thank you for the example! It would be good to have such a non-blocking example with return value in the reactor netty tcp docs as the docs only have blocking examples and the then().then(...) syntax is a bit counter-intuitive on first contact.